# NameError - undefined local variable or method `favorites'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby... I am getting a name error in user.rb

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `favorites' for #<User:0x007fc0e19a8720>:
  activemodel (4.0.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:167:in `method_missing'
  app/models/user.rb:17:in `favorited'
  app/views/favorites/_favorite.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_favorites__favorite_html_erb__4203159933335848505_70233146456940'
```

This is my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def role?(base_role)
    role == base_role.to_s
  end

  def favorited(post)
    favorites.where(post_id: post.id).first
  end

end
```

This is my favorite.rb file:

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

end

I don't understand why I am getting the name error.

Comment: You haven't defined an association called `favourites`.

Answer (score 3):

Your error reads:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `favorites' for #<User:0x007fc0e19a8720>
```

In other words, it's telling you that you're calling the method `favorites` on a `User` instance, and that method isn't defined for that object type.

That makes sense given your `user.rb` file, which has neither the user-favorites association (which would automatically create that method for you), nor an explicit `def favorites` method. To avoid this error, you need one or the other.

I agree with Vimsha's suggestion -- this looks like an association, for which you're better off using Rails's built in association methods (probably `has_many :favorites`) than writing the methods for that association yourself.